# UIStackView subviews with size classes

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard, uistackview, size-classes

Trying to achieve UIStackView with 2 labels for iPhone and 3 labels for iPad using size classes.

View hierarchy

1. **Default size class**

   ```
   [UIStackView] 
     [UILabel 1] [UILabel2]
   [UIStackView]
   ```

   [image]
2. **RxR size class**

   ```
   [UIStackView] 
     [UILabel 1] [UILabel2] [UILabel3]
   [UIStackView]
   ```

   [image]

It looks exactly as expected in Storyboard as you can see in the above screenshots but on simulator iPad view is messed up.

**iPhone Output** (okay)

[image]

**iPad Portrait Output** (messed up)

[image]

**iPad Landscape Output** (messed up)
[image]

What's happening in iPad?? Is it a bug or I'm missing something? 
Thanks.

I have created a [sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9ez7rs7g7n7c9k/sizeclasstest.zip?dl=0).

Comment: What about constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below steps to achieve your requirements :

- Drag one horizontal Stackview in to your interface builder
- set it's constraints like : `top,leading, =trailing and fixed height`
- Drag and drop three labels in to it and select all together and set one constraint : **`Equal width`**
- now select second or middle label and from `attribute inspector` click on `+` button beside `installed` and select Regular for both width and height. It will add regular,regular variation and `uncheck the checkbox for that R,R variation`. Refer below screen shot for better understanding,

[image]

And you are done! now you your center label will not show in iPad and every label will be displayed in iPhone!

See below result screenshot of `iphone and ipad` in my case!

iPhone :

[image]

iPad :

[image]

**Update :**

If you want two to hide label in iPhone and show in iPad then add one more variation : `Compact Width Regular Height` for middle label and uncheck the checkbox to uninstall. Refer below screenshot,

[image]

Comment: thanks, it works but I want to show 3 labels in ipad and 2 labels in iphone. So what i did is. 1. Select middle label. 2 checked the checkbox for that R,R variation 3. uncheck the default checkbox. Again iphone is okay but ipad views are messed up.

Comment: @Bilal Initially you said that you want to hide label in iPad so I have written answer accordingly. But now if you want to hide label in iPhone and want to show in iPad then you should add one more variation `cW Rh` and do uninstall for that ! Check my update in answer!

Comment: I think you misunderstood, question says the same "UIStackView with 2 labels for iPhone and 3 labels for iPad using size classes". But thanks a lot, I got what I need with little amendments.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are hiding one of the labels on iPhone using the "installed" checkbox in Interface Builder. Using the "hidden" checkbox instead seems to solve the problem. Which I guess is a bug.